# Can we do CQRS without axon in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, cqrs, axon

I want to know that can we do CQRS without axon server in spring boot application and other thing is what are the axon alternative Frameworks for spring boot?
And also what are the difference between axon community edition avd the enterprise edition? How does affect it when we the horizontal scaling the application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing the title of your question should be `Axon Server` i.o. `Axon`. Axon would contain both Axon Server and Axon Framework. The former provides an Event Store and Distributed Message Routing solution. The latter provides building blocks towards a DDD, CQRS, Event Sourcing application, using location transparency (through messaging) to enhance microservice options.

However, neither of these components are ever requirements to use any architectural pattern, just like Levi points out. Axon Framework just simplifies the construction of a CQRS/DDD/ES application by giving *a lot* of building blocks to achieve this.

As stated, Axon Server is an application that stores your events (to support Event Sourcing as intended) and routes messages taking the different routing patterns of Commands, Events, and Queries into account. Using Axon Server with Axon Framework is also **not** a requirement. It just simplifies your application landscape, providing the right optimizations for DDD/CQRS/ES applications.

Answer (score 3):

CQRS being an architectural pattern, you can most definitely do CQRS in vanilla Spring Boot.  It might require you to break up the read side and write side in separately deployed services and manually arrange to keep them eventually consistent.